# MS graph api - scope access to particular user inbox

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have an app registered on Azure AD (we got app ID, secret, redirect URL). This app is a daemon/background application which is performing actions on behalf of a user, there is *no* signed-in user that can grant permissions. In particular, the app will periodically retrieve all emails from a particular outlook mailbox called `my.test@org.com`

We are following [the permission scoping documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access) and the [permission documentation when there is no signed in user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service).
In my understanding we need

- to give application-permissions on the API permissions page in Azure AD
- create a security group which is somehow assigned to the mailbox we want to read from via

```
    New-ApplicationAccessPolicy   
      -AppId e7e4dbfc-046f-4074-9b3b-2ae8f144f59b   
      -PolicyScopeGroupId EvenUsers@contoso.com    <-- would I put here my.test@org.com or the ID of the security group? 
      -AccessRight RestrictAccess   
      -Description "Restrict this app to members of distribution group EvenUsers."
```

Is my understanding correct that both of the above steps are needed. It seems strange that in the first step we can only give tenant wide permissions to the application when we really only need to limit it to one particular mailbox.

Thanks for the help

Comment: The above steps looks good to me and i would do the same. Just provide necessary Graph permissions while you grant permissions to access your/others mailboxes - as described in the [documentation/steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access)

Comment: Application permission is tenant wide permission and usually requires admin consent as you observed. Don't worry about that because if you do the second step, the access permissions are limited to the particular user mailbox.

Comment: Thanks @AllenWu, I agree and don't worry about it per se, but our IT mgmt goes crazy when they hear "tenant-wide". I don't particularly like this top-down approach of permissioning (why start wide and then narrow down??). We might have to go with a signed-in-user permission model

Answer (score 1):

The above steps looks good to me and i would do the same as well. Just provide necessary Graph permissions while you grant permissions to access your/others mailboxes - as described in the  [documentation/steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access).